# convert binary to decimal how can i ask the user to input only binary

Tags: c++

I'm trying to ask the user to only input binary number lets say (11110) which is (30) in decimal
but the out put is always like this 
enter a binary number : 11110 - only binary number are allowed - the answer is : 30
also i have been asked not to use any library or function.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    long int binary, decimal = 0, j, base = 1;
    cout << " enter a binary number : ";
    cin >> binary;
    char r[40] = { " " }; int s[40];

    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        if (r[i] != '0') {
            if (r[i] != '1') {
                if (r[i] != '\0') {
                    cout << "Only binary numbers are allowed\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        if (r[i] == '0')
            s[i] = 0;
        if (r[i] == '1')
            s[i] = 1;


    }
    while (binary != 0)
    {
        j = binary % 10;
        decimal += j * base;
        base *= 2;
        binary /= 10;

    }
    cout <<" the answerr is : "<< decimal << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to parse the input and if it doesn't match what you expected loop back and ask for input again.  Try implementing that.

Comment: You never write anything into `r` - why do you expect to find `0` and `1` characters there? In particular, you set `r[0]` to be a space character. So clearly `r[0] != '0'`, and `r[0] != '1'`, and `r[0] != '\0'`

Comment: Also, computing the answer involves neither `r` nor `s`. It's unclear why you even have them.

Answer (score 0):

You've created an input array of size 40, setting the first character to a space. However, you never read the user's input into that array! It's stuck in the variable `binary`. As a result, `r[0]` (the first thing checked) will always equal , which will cause your `for` loop to fail.

Consider the following 2 changes:

- When you initialize the array, fill it with null terminators as so: `char r[40] = {};`
- Convert `binary` to a string or char array, and read it into `r` to check for invalid input.

If you want to avoid strings altogether, you can simply use the modulo operator instead to verify there's no digits besides 0 or 1.

```cpp
long int temp = binary;

while(temp > 0) {
  if(temp % 10 > 1) {
    std::cout << "Input can only be binary!" << std::endl;
    //do something
  }
  temp = temp / 10; //integer math will cut the lsb
}
```

Comment: Actually the ```r``` array is only filled with 1 space + 39 null bytes with this line: ```char r[40] = { " " };```. It can be initialized with all null bytes like this: ```char r[40] = {};```

Comment: @foolo You're quite correct, updating my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to keep the input as a string, validates it then convert it to number, like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
{
    bool     result  = false;
    long int decimal = 0;

    while (!result)
    {
        string binary;
        cout << " enter a binary number : ";
        cin >> binary;

        bool success = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); ++i)
            if (binary[i] != '0' && binary[i] != '1')
            {
                cout << "Only binary numbers are allowed\n";
                success = false;
                break;
            }

        if (!success)
            continue;

        long int binNb, j, base = 1;

        binNb = atoi(binary.c_str());

        while (binNb)
        {
            j        = binNb % 10;
            decimal += j * base;
            base    *= 2;
            binNb   /= 10;
        }

        result = true;
    }

    cout <<" the answer is : "<< decimal << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But it's true that, although it shows a clearer code than in the Nick Reed answer, this solution may be a little less efficient, because it requires 2 loops instead of 1.

It's as you prefer.